# problem for program to read n last lines from file in c

Tags: c

I have a problem on my code which return the n last line from file, when I enter 8 it return 4 lines, 6 -> 3 last lines, 4 -> 2 last line and so on.

this is my code:

```
FILE* file;
int count = 0;
int pos;
char s[1000];
int numberOfline;

printf("Enter the number of last line to return: ");
scanf_s("%d", &numberOfline);

file = fopen("lines.txt", "rt+");
if (file == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
pos = ftell(file);
while (pos) {
    fseek(file, --pos, SEEK_SET);
    if (fgetc(file) == '\n') {
        if (count++ == numberOfline) break;
    }
}
while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), file) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", s);
}
fclose(file);
```

what is the problem and why he accept only even number and return the half of it, and how can i fix that?

Comment: Maybe read the file with a hex editor to verify there's only one `'\n'` at the end of the line.

Comment: The last line of a text file does not always end with a newline.

Comment: If it is a Windows text file with `0D 0A` line endings and you are reading them in reverse order, perhaps each one is counted as a newline. So two newlines per text line. This is a cack-handed way to find the number of lines anyway. Count them by reading the file and then `rewind()` and start over, ignoring the first `count - numberOfline` lines.

Comment: Just tested, and that is the case: reading the CR LF pair in reverse order reads two newline characters, not one.

Answer (score 0):

**Undefined behavior**

`fseek()` on a text file is well defined for the beginning and positions from previous `ftell()`.

OP is attempting an `fseek()` from every file position.

OP's woe of double counting is that an `fget()` sees `"\r\n:` and `"\n:` both as `'\n`.